# IndexError: list index out of range - Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to plot a graph by taking the coordinates from a file . While doing so  I came across an error . Heres the code :

```
 import matplotlib
 import matplotlib.pyplot as pt

  x = [] 
  y = [] 
 file = open(r"E:\test.txt", "r")
 data = file.read().split("\n")
 for i in data:
 val = i.split(" , ")
 x.append([val[0]])
 y.append([val[1]]) 
  print("Data = " + str(data))
  print("X Axis = " + str(x))
  print("Y Axis = " + str(y))
```

And I get this error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "E:/PROGRAMS/PyCharm 2016 IDE/PycharmProjects/Apps/Matplot.py", line 11, in <module>
   y.append([val[1]])
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you fix indentations of your code first?

Comment: Evidently `val` contains only one item. Have you added some `print`s to find out what you're working with? Also note that the `csv`  module does most of what you want, and it's awkward and unnecessary to read the whole file and split it on line breaks yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Next bit of code assumes that each line has at least one sequence of " , " what if some line doesnt?

```
 val = i.split(" , ")
 x.append([val[0]])
 y.append([val[1]])
```

A more defensive approach

```
 val = i.split(" , ")
 if len(val) == 2:
     x.append([val[0]])
     y.append([val[1]])
```